# Are there any auto-indent tools for device tree source (.dts, .dtsi) files?

Tags: vim, auto-indent, device-tree

Does anyone know of any tools which can help with indenting .dts/dtsi files? Vim does not seem to have one and emacs has [dts-mode](https://github.com/bgamari/dts-mode/) but it does not handle C-style multi-line comments in a way that I prefer. Are there any other source code indentation or formatting tools that are known to work with device tree files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, since there doesn't appear to be any, I've started working on [vim-dts-indent](https://github.com/jyelloz/vim-dts-indent). It's not that good yet but it works okay on reasonably-sized blocks.

My main goals are to fall back to cindent when in the middle of a C-style comment to avoid lots of work and integrate un-indentation of C preprocessor directives.